# Ggplot - How to present the mean of a third varience?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have this data frame:

[The data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKUAs.png)

I want to make a graph which presents for each SES (Social Economy Status) what is the mean income for females and what is the mean income for males.

I have so far this code:

```
ggplot(incomeSorted, aes(GENDER)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Mean")+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap("SES")
```

and this is the output:

[image]

How do I make the graph to present the mean of income instead of counting the number of females and males at each category?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display mean income, you have to compute it. You can use `dplyr` and `group_by()` with `summarise()` to obtain the key variable and then plot. Here a code for the task:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(id=1:8,Gender=c(rep('Female',4),rep(c('Male','Female'),2)),
                 income=c(73,150,220.18,234,314.16,983.1,1001,1012),
                 SES=c('Bottom','Bottom','Middle','Middle','Middle',
                       'Upper','Upper','Upper'),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
#Compute and plot
df %>% group_by(SES,Gender) %>%
  summarise(MeanIncome=mean(income,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Gender,y=MeanIncome)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Mean")+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  facet_wrap(.~SES)
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can avoid facets and displaying the plot with a `fill` variable like this:

```
#Code 2
df %>% group_by(SES,Gender) %>%
  summarise(MeanIncome=mean(income,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Gender,y=MeanIncome,fill=SES)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Mean")+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast comment!
When I tried the first code, i got this error:

Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `SES`.
* Plot is missing `SES`
* Layer 1 is missing `SES`

What should I do?

Comment: @pdoron Hi! Did you tried first with the `df` data I included? I tried to creating a similar data as those you showed in an image. Your error looks like something missing. Check the names of your dataframe and that all packages mentioned here are loaded. Let me know how that goes!